# Best practice for deleting related entities in normalized state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalization

When deleting an entity from normalized data, how do we deal with deleting other entities that are owned by the deleted entity? For example, for the following normalized data, if I'm going to delete `user1`, I would also like to delete all posts and comments made by `user1`. Are there any known how-tos or best practices for this situation?

```
{
    posts : {
        byId : {
            "post1" : {
                id : "post1",
                author : "user1",
                body : "......",
                comments : ["comment1", "comment2"]    
            }
        },
        allIds : ["post1"]
    },
    comments : {
        byId : {
            "comment1" : {
                id : "comment1",
                author : "user1",
                comment : ".....",
            },
            "comment2" : {
                id : "comment2",
                author : "user1",
                comment : ".....",
            },
        },
        allIds : ["comment1", "comment2"]
    },
    users : {
        byId : {
            "user1" : {
                username : "user1",
                name : "User 1",
            }
        },
        allIds : ["user1"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using [normalized-reducer](https://github.com/brietsparks/normalized-reducer) for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can look at this:

1. The reducers for each element are responsible for cleaning up the data for any action which deletes a user, or;
2. The action of deleting a user has the side effect of deleting a number of associated items (or a number of associated actions are dispatched)

## Option 1

Let's say you have an action like the following:

```
  const deleteUser = userId => {
    return ({
      type: 'DELETE_USER',
      userId
    })
  }
```

Your reducer for `user` might look like this:

```
  const users = (state = {}, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
      case 'DELETE_USER':
        // delete user logic
        break;
    }

  }
```

Well there's technically nothing in Redux that stops you from reacting to the `DELETE_USER` action in the `posts` or `comments` reducers:

```
  const posts = (state = {}, action) => {
    const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'DELETE_USER':
        // delete posts for action.userId
        break;
    }
  }
```

## Option 2

If you don't like the above, and want to keep some degree of separation of concerns, then consider looking at a way to trigger side-effects associated with an action, such as [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) or [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

The implementation will vary depending on the library, but the idea is:

1. Listen for `DELETE_USER` action
2. Trigger some actions to:

   1. Delete a user (`DELETE_USER`)
   2. Delete posts for a user (`DELETE_USER_POSTS`)
   3. Delete comments for a user (`DELETE_USER_COMMENTS`)

Comment: It's easy to delete the `posts` depending on the `user.id`, because the posts have a field refering to the user, but how do you delete `comments` depending on a `post` ? You have no field inside `comments` to do this.